# How do I use Apport on a virtual console to send a bug report?

Tags: bug-reporting

I am experiencing several bugs in Ubuntu 19.10:

1. When pasting, often I paste not the newest copied/cut text/image, but the previous one. Very annoying! It is the case in all programs (LibreOffice, Kate, Firefox etc.).
2. When a program has problems - e.g. because something takes a long time, and it offers to wait or close down, sometimes the whole computer becomes unresponsive - I can move the mouse, but not change to other running programs. In the end, I have to hard reboot.
3. Sometimes the laptop keyboard becomes somewhat unresponsive. I can move the mouse, change programs etc., but when I type, it takes forever for the letter to turn up - and then a number of the same letter is typed. Even after a restart, it is the case (which makes it impossible to log in). When I close down, wait a few seconds, and restart, it works again.

So I wanted to report these errors - and I guess it has to do with xorg, so I hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, and:

```
ubuntu-bug xorg
```

The data is collected, and I hit send. Then nothing happens. According to this page: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs, I should see a webpage where I should provide more information. But I don't...

Anyone who could help me on how to get these bugs reported?

Answer (score 0):

example

```
 apport-bug /var/crash/_usr_bin_lxqt-globalkeysd.1000.crash
```

If a running program acts wired for you.

```
pidof programname
```

get the pid of running Prozess.

```
apport-bug PID
```

I'm not good in explaining. Please take also a look in

```
man apport-collect
```